# Issue using array of objects from API as JSON for d3 visualization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, d3.js

So I built an API that returns an array like this:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Josh","parent":null},
{"id":2,"name":"Peter","parent":1},{"id":3,"name":"Mary","parent":2}]
```

I'm able to use it on my react app to display a table but now I'd like to use it as input for a d3 graph. Because of that, I built a function that takes an array of objects and transforms it to one big hierarchical one.

```
function convert(array){    
    var map = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        var obj = array[i];
        obj.children= [];

        map[obj.id] = obj;

        var parent = obj.parent || '-';
        if(!map[parent]){
            map[parent] = {
                children: []
            };
        }
        map[parent].children.push(obj);
    }

    return map['-'].children;
```

The problem is that when I pass what I get from API using axios.get, it gives an undefined error as if it weren't able to parse the objects inside the array.

If on the other hand, I manually insert the same array:

```
const rawData2 = [{"id":1,"name":"Javier","parent":null},
{"id":2,"name":"Nerea","parent":1}, 
{"id":3,"name":"Yolo","parent":2}]
```

it works without a problem.

I don't know what else to try. I tried stringfy, parse json, using a map like this:

```
var result = this.state.persons.map(person => ({id: person.id, name: person.name, parent: 
person.parent}))
```

Nothing works.

Any help?

EDIT: I think the problem has something to do with the fact that JS is asynchronous so when I pass the API response to my convert function I also pass some empty arrays before I actually pass the actual arrays from the data.

How can I lock the data to avoid this? Sorry for my lack of technical vocabulary but I'm quite new to this type of languages.

Edit2: This is how I retrieve data from API:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this._refreshAliens()
  }

  _refreshAliens () {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/aliens').then((response) => {
      this.setState({
        aliens: response.data
      })
     });
```

And then I just simply do:
convert(this.state.aliens) giving me the error: Can add property children to undefined.

If I console.log(this.state.aliens):

I get some [], [] and then (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}] with the correct data.

EDit:

```
render() {
    let aliens = this.state.aliens.map((alien) => {
      return (
        <tr key={alien.id}>
          <td>{alien.id}</td>
          <td>{alien.name}</td>
          <td>{alien.type}</td>
          <td>{alien.planet}</td>
          <td>{alien.parent}</td>
          <td>
            <Button color="success" size="sm" className="mr-2" onClick={this.editAlien.bind(this, alien.id, alien.name, alien.planet)}>Edit</Button>
            <Button color="danger" size="sm" onClick={this.deleteAlien.bind(this, alien.id)}>Delete</Button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      )
      })
    const { all = [] } = this.state.aliens
      if (Array.isArray(all) && all.length === 0) {
        return <p>Loading...</p>
      } 
    return (

      <div className="App container">

          ...........
```

Edit Error:

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name, type, planet, parent}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

_refreshAliens/<
src/App.js:60

```
  57 | }
  58 | _refreshAliens () {
  59 |   axios.get('http://localhost:8080/aliens').then((response) => {
> 60 |     this.setState({
     | ^  61 |       aliens: response.data
  62 |     })
  63 |
```

Comment: Can you share your code where you do api call and pass response to your convert function.

Comment: @AadilMehraj I just edited my post

Comment: Where is this line written? convert(this.state.aliens)

Comment: Inside render() {.....} as let data = convert(this.state.aliens

Answer (score 2):

During the time API request take place, aliens state will be an empty array. You need to handle that case in your convert function as well. Add a null check to avoid error at the return in that case.

```
function convert(array = []){    
    var map = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        var obj = array[i];
        obj.children= [];

        map[obj.id] = obj;

        var parent = obj.parent || '-';
        if(!map[parent]){
            map[parent] = {
                children: []
            };
        }
        map[parent].children.push(obj);
    }

    return map['-'] ? map['-'].children : null;
}
```

Edit: Also add loader to avoid further error in case data from API is available, like this in your render function:

```
render() {
  const { aliens = [] } = this.state
  if (Array.isArray(aliens) && aliens.length === 0) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>
  }

  return (
    // Do your stuff...
  )

}
```

EDIT 2: Make sure you destructure aliens from the state properly. This is how the resulting code should look:

```
render() {
  const {aliens = []}= this.state;

  if (!Array.isArray(aliens) || aliens.length === 0) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>
  } 

  return (

      <div className="App container">
         {
            aliens.map((alien) => {
              return (
                <tr key={alien.id}>
                  <td>{alien.id}</td>
                  <td>{alien.name}</td>
                  <td>{alien.type}</td>
                  <td>{alien.planet}</td>
                  <td>{alien.parent}</td>
                  <td>
                    <Button color="success" size="sm" className="mr-2" onClick={this.editAlien.bind(this, alien.id, alien.name, alien.planet)}>Edit</Button>
                    <Button color="danger" size="sm" onClick={this.deleteAlien.bind(this, alien.id)}>Delete</Button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              )
            })
         }

         // Other stuff...
      </div>
    )
```

Comment: Now the function doesn't raise an error but it still outputs some nulls what gives me an error when I pass hierarchy(convert(data)) using D3. Is it possible to ignore those empty sub arrays and not output anything? Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it be an else clause somewhere? My web is stuck at Loading now.

Comment: You don't need else you are returning in the first if clause, make sure your condition is right.

Comment: I edited my post. I did as you said but my page is stuck at Loading..

Comment: Updated the answer make sure you destructure aliens from state properly.

Comment: I have updated the condition for my last edit. Check if it resolves the error.